# Update clojure code running in a thread

Tags: clojure, reload

Now, I need some kind of code reloading in the clojure/java mixing system.

I know tools.namespace lib can be used to refresh clj code. But when I try to reload code which is used in a thread, it is not updated.

This is the example clojure code I need to update: (just switch between upper case and lower case.)

```
(ns com.test.test-util)
(defn get-word [sentence]
    (let [a-word (rand-nth (clojure.string/split sentence #"\s"))
        ;;a-word (clojure.string/upper-case a-word)
        ]
        (println a-word)
        a-word))
```

I used a future to start a thread and call the code above.

In main method, in my first test, I just create a future and refresh the code after a while. But it is not updated. So, I also tested to create another thread after refresh. But the code is not updated.

```
(defn start-job []
  (future (
            (println "start worker job.")
            (while @job-cond
              (do (get-word (rand-nth sentences))
                (Thread/sleep 2000)) )
            (println "return!")
            )))

(defn -main []
  (let [work-job (start-job)]
    (println "modify clj file...")
    (Thread/sleep 10000)
    (swap! job-cond not)
    (future-cancel work-job)
    (swap! job-cond not)

    (refresh)
    (Thread/sleep 3000)

    (let [new-work-job (start-job)]
      (Thread/sleep 10000)
      (swap! job-cond not)
      (future-cancel new-work-job))))
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have extraneous parenthesis that are guaranteed to cause an NPE in the start-job definition. Unquoted parenthesis do not group code blocks in clojure, they invoke a function or macro call. Future has an implicit do block, so you don't need to wrap the code block inside future. Also the do in the while block is unneeded, as while also has an implicit do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you don't want code-reloading to affect runtime. Rather you should try to seek for clean ways to boot and shutdown the running application code using e. g. Stuart Sierras library `component` or `juxt/jig` by Malcolm Sparks. Then reload namespaces only when your application *is not* up and running (or at least not the parts of running code that depend on namespaces being reloaded).

That being said, here is why your example does not work:

`start-job` can not automatically refer to a reloaded version of `get-word` in its lifetime because the version of `get-work` it uses is resolved when it is compiled. So it will still use the old version.

Explicitly resolve the var of `get-word` using

```
(resolve `get-word)
```

and invoke the returned var as a function instead of using `get-word` directly in the future.

What will happen then?
After you made the changes and `refresh` has been invoked, `-main` will still refer to the old-version of `start-job` (so if you change that, it will not show effect in runtime). However within that `get-word` will be resolved as described above and the new version of `get-word` will be used.

**Short explanation**: You can't expect a running compiled function to replace itself with reloaded code on the fly (no matter whether it runs on a separate thread or not). That would (unless you are using `resolve` in it) be a necessity though for it to invoke reloaded functions.

Comment: I think you can expect to reload code on the fly, it just depends on the technique. For example it's a common idiom in Ring applications to pass '#var as the handler, like `run-jetty '#app` rather than `run-jetty app`. So if you change the function the var refers to and reevaluate var, you'll get the new code on the fly.

Comment: You are right for re-evaluation. For reloading namespaces it won't work, though. Re-evaluation means that you simply re-evaluate the form in the current environment, meaning that `defn` will be invoked which will only alter the root-binding of the var. If you pass a var instead of a function, it's root-binding will be looked up before calling. If you are reloading a namespace however, the var (including its root-binding) will be forgotten (together with the namespace class containing it) and you can find the new version only in the newly loaded namespace.

Comment: Thanks.
What I am planning is using Stuart Sierras's component lib to reload the worker. And refresh the code before reset it.